# How hard scifi is a graviton gravity drive?

Tags: propulsion, artificial-gravity

What if, hypothetically, gravitons could be captured and stored. Then, a beam of gravitons is projected in front of the ship, each individual graviton not having much pull, but together, warping space enough to create a gravity well and pull the ship forward. Soon, the gravitons disperse and the gravity well with them, but the ship continues projecting a gravity well in front of its self pulling it further and further forward. To slow down, the forward graviton beam is shut off, and a hind graviton beam is activated creating gravity wells behind the ship to diminish its forward speed.

If it were possible to create such temporary wells, the ship could hypothetically accelerate and decelerate at speeds that would normally be thousands of Gs for the crew, but without adverse effects, as the crew would be in freefall.

Is this hypothetically possible as an (advanced) propulsion system, or is it still a fantasy reactionless drive? I feel as though this would not fall into the usual "puling yourself up by your bootstraps" error of most proposed gravity drives, as the ship is not pushing the artificial gravity source with its weight, but continuously generating new gravity wells as the older ones dissipate, and expending a limited number of particles for fuel, but I may very well be wrong.

Comment: Do these graviton thingies possess inertial mass? Are you carrying them with you in a big tank, or making them on the fly? (Pun unintentional).

Comment: Carried in some sort of containment unit and harvested from a gravity source with great mass, such as a blackhole or iron star

Comment: Weren't you previously a member? You know you can use the [contact form](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/contact) found at the bottom left of each page to (request to) merge accounts if you'd like.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. [gravitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) the ones and only _massless_ spin-2 particles (unless you discover another field that acts a gravity but is not gravity)

Comment: 1) The idea has already been around for a long time in fiction; the KK drive (Alan Dean Foster) and Fasset drive (David Weber) are gravity well based propulsion.  2) Launching gravitons ahead of the ship would pull anything they contacted toward the ship, not produce a gravity well.  If anything, I'd expect the ship to recoil slightly from launching the gravitons.

Comment: It would be so much efficient if you just keep a big tank of electrons. I mean, the electromagnetic interaction is so much stronger than the gravitational force. Dealing with those electrons will also reveal the weakness of your "beam of gravitons" that you intend _to project_ in front of your ship - assuming Newtonian physics holds, the simple act of projecting them in from of your ship will throw your ship back, to a net of zero speed or worse. If Newtonian physics doesn't hold, then we're dealing with magic here.

Comment: Hello Ben. Here at [worldbuilding.se] we help people create and consistently use the rules and systems of fictional worlds of their own creation. You don't appear to be doing this... or are you? Asking if a fictional drive meets the expectations of science fiction (no matter how "hard") doesn't make sense. If you're asking if this can exist in Real Life, it's off-topic here without a worldbuilding context and should be asked at [physics.se]. If you are asking in a worldbuilding context, what's your question?

Comment: It may just be my lack of understanding of gravitons but as far as my understanding of gravity goes things don't tend to disperse if there's a well of the stuff and will more than likely stick together and continually attract more stuff. Would that sort of thing not mess with it?

Comment: "Gravitons" would *not* produce a well where they are going to, they would (effectively) produce a well ***where they came from***.

Comment: This concept sort of reminds me of the of the Mass Effect video game franchise's  [eponymous technology](https://masseffect.fandom.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_Field), which could make an area of empty space behave as if it had mass. It used dark energy (somehow) to create this effect rather than direct manipulation of gravitons.

Comment: Can a beam of photons be used to attract an electrically charged ship? No, it can't

Answer (score 12):

> What if, hypothetically, gravitons could be captured and stored.

A couple of "hard sci-fi" problems with this.

Firstly gravitons are massless (or more precisely are expected to massless as we have not detected them).  Massless particles *always* travel at the speed of light.  They cannot be "stored".  Like photons (also massless) you can only absorb them, converting them to another form of energy, and then generating a new photon from that.

So what you need (for hard sci-fi) is a way to *generate* gravitons from an energy source.

> Then, a beam of gravitons is projected in front of the ship, each individual graviton not having much pull, but together, warping space enough to create a gravity well and pull the ship forward.

This is kind of dubious as it presumes the gravitons will bend space.  It's not impossible, but you're making two mistakes.  Again hard sci-fi.

Directing your beam of gravitons forward will mean they have a forward momentum (being massless does not mean they don't have momentum, photons have momentum and they're massless too).  But that momentum has to be balanced by the change in momentum of the ship, which means the ship is *slowed down* by the act of projecting gravitons forward.

The net effect, because the universe seems to work like this, is that you won't go any faster, but would in fact go *slower*.

The universe always *strictly* balances the books.

The second problem is the amount of energy required to bend space significantly enough to be useful.  That's a *huge* amount of energy and the pwoer required would be better used to simply direct a beam of photons *behind* the ship so it acts like a photon rocket.  This is technologically simpler (ignoring the tricky bit - generating the power which you're doing anyway).

> Soon, the gravitons disperse and the gravity well with them, but the ship continues projecting a gravity well in front of its self pulling it further and further forward. To slow down, the forward graviton beam is shut off, and a hind graviton beam is activated creating gravity wells behind the ship to diminish its forward speed.

Again the deceleration process would probably have the opposite effect, because momentum and energy conservation work that way.

> If it were possible to create such temporary wells, the ship could hypothetically accelerate and decelerate at speeds that would normally be thousands of Gs for the crew, but without adverse effects, as the crew would be in freefall.

No, they'd be accelerating or dsecelerating or they smash into the ship's front or back because the ship is accelerating or decelerating.

> Is this hypothetically possible as an (advanced) propulsion system, or is it still a fantasy reactionless drive? I feel as though this would not fall into the usual "puling yourself up by your bootstraps" error of most proposed gravity drives, as the ship is not pushing the artificial gravity source with its weight, but continuously generating new gravity wells as the older ones dissipate, and expending a limited number of particles for fuel, but I may very well be wrong.

If you're seriously thinking of this in hard sci-fi terms I would say this is a non-starter.

The main problem for all forms of propulsion system for hard sci-fi is the power generation.  Once you can generate the power there are those handy photons to use for propulsion.

Comment: That "gravitons" travel at the speed of light doesn't preclude storing them, per se. They could be traveling in (small) circular paths... probably...

Comment: @PabloH I am open to hearing a hard sci-fi justification for having gravitons travel in a circular path.  I am inclined to say that, if possible at all, it would require a lot of power that could be put to simpler uses in propelling the ship.

Comment: Photons do not always travel at *c*. That’s the speed of light *in a vacuum*. Photons can and do travel slower—in some exotic materials, even slow enough to be “slow” by the standards of human perception. (Of course, zoomed in enough, the photons are still traveling at *c* and just hitting stuff and bouncing around a lot on the way through—and you’d presumably never hit 0. Even “bouncing around” might more accurately termed “getting absorbed and re-output.”) Anyway, if a static material could “slow” gravitons down in such a manner, it might make keeping them on a circular path easier?

Comment: @KRyan You're basically heading into exotic materials territory or personal mini-black holes stuff, and I'd again question whether such things (or the effort to make them) could be put into more direct use with less difficulty.    It all feels very handwavium to me, but it's hard sci-fi not rigorous physics - there is a difference - so it depends on how much you can get away with as an author.

Comment: I like almost all of your answer, except for the smashing against the walls of the ship. Presumably, the ship itself is in free fall as well. The problem is of a different nature altogether. Being very close to the... er... "center" of a gravity well means the time distortion at the front of the ship is *very* different from that at the back of the ship. No, the real problem here is that the tidal forces would rip the ship apart. But if the ship could withstand that, then anything inside the ship would be as much in free fall as it would be inside one of those zero-g-experience airplanes.